# The fastest way to check internet access(or an instant signal from operating system)

Tags: c#

I've come up with a scenario in which, I need to instantly know whether I have internet access or not.

I've tried different solutions, many of them are about checking network connection. I need to check internet access.

Is it possible to khow it instantly without sending any request??(for example using operating system instant signals if there is any)

If instant is impossible, which method can be the fastest to achieve this??

Any tested answers will help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll never be able to do this reliably *and* instantly. What's the actual problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I can't think of any real reason that milliseconds would make a difference in well designed client/server code;  Even if you have access to a resource, data loss is still possible, so fault tolerant web services are checking the validity of data retrieved, and no data would be equally as bad as corrupt data, thus handling both contingencies.

Comment: @Roger and Claies .It is about crawling with selenium. I need to be informed the moment I lose internet access and stop my thread,otherwise, I have to face DDOS checking for my next reuest, which will take at least 5 seconds. The site's server is strong and there  are nearly 500 requests(better to say crawler requests) just like mine in a second.since this is a win or lose game, I should deal with milliseconds.
I wonder how OS realize this?? Is it realized by the first unsuccessful request??

Comment: Thanks downvoter! I'm looking for a solution to this problem.May be one another guy can use the answer of this question someday.I'm not looking for bounus.

Comment: "otherwise, I have to face DDOS checking for my next reuest" ... explain?

Comment: @Efe You can try out my code, put it in a while loop and specify a timer to check for the internet connection periodically. You can use a separate thread to run this listener.

Comment: This site had ddos attacks recently.so, your initial request is checked by the site promting "the request is checking your browser for any possible ddos attacks and ..." it takes 5 seconds. This checking also occurs whenever you change your ip, or set an incomplete request(my problem, an instant loss of internet access).Also, you cannot access the site from two browsers by one ip(blocks you).I've overcome this problem with browser profiles, however, my code needs to know internet loss to apply another politic

Comment: define "as soon as". Is 1s delay acceptable or it has to be absolute instant? If its absolute instant then you are out of luck. 1s delay you can always ping some site that's > 99.999% of the time every 1s

Comment: @Steve Good point. You say instant is not possible. I wanna know why. Will OS realize internet loss without having any up or downstream?? I stated milliseconds are important in my scenario, because one method can last 2000 ms and the other can last 2300 ms to get me to my answer One says ping google,other says ping youtube, and the third one says use webclient and ... . If instant is not possible, which piece of code can be the fastest.As my question's title says.

Comment: @Efe I believe OS uses the same way. Which way is the fastest? try it yourself.

Comment: @Steve yes. You are right. I am on it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
 public static bool IsInternetAvailable()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                using (client.OpenRead("YOUR_WEBSITE_NAME"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you exactly say what OpenRead does?? My website name is not important, Im looking for not to send any requests if possible, or at least the lightest request. Does OpenRead wait for response???

Comment: This is from MSDN *"Opens a readable stream for the data downloaded from a resource with the URI specified as a String."*

Comment: Great. I need to benchmark your suggested code. Currently Im gathering all new solutions and I must compare them. I Promise to inform you.Sameer, I would appriciating your alernative answers and any recoms.